# How to load deployment class loaders in jboss 7.1.x

Tags: java, jboss7.x

I have deployed war file in C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments\sample.war in that deployed 
sample.war/web-inf/empInfo.xml

how Should i load empInfo.xml in runtime?

i have tried ,it gives null value

```
 InputStream settingsStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("empInfo.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move it to the class path. The `WEB-INF` directory is not on the deployments class path. Move it to `WEB-INF/classes` and it should be found.